# debugging .NET application loading slowness

Tags: vb.net, performance, compilation

I have an application written using Windows Forms and complied against Visual Studio 2010.
We recently upgraded the solution to Visual Studio 2013 and changed to using hard references to using NuGet to manage dependencies.

The application runs on a terminal server.

When running the application on the terminal server using a version compiled using 2010, it opens instantly. When running a version compiled using 2013, it takes many minutes to open.

How can I find out why the application takes so long to open the initial form?
Any thoughts or ideas about why changing these two things have made the application so slow?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you check there are processes which eating too many memories?

Comment: Theres 16GB of memory available on this terminal server. No other users logged in. 3GB of memory in use by other processes etc.

Comment: How about when trying to open the app compiled using 2013?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of debugging, I found out that the MySql.Data.dll component is executing queries twice as slow as previous versions. I downgraded to version 6.3.8 in Nuget and this has increased the speed dramatically.

I hope this helps someone with similar slowness - and using the MySql component set.